# SQL Server : search in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to search in my SQL Server 2008 column. The column called `lstclasseshas` and its values look like `8100, 8200, 8300, 8400` for a single row

I am trying the following techniques to get me a result but none of them is working

What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT *
FROM response_students
INNER JOIN response ON response_students.responseID = reponseID
--where classid = #arguments.cid#
--where ','+lstclasses+',' LIKE '%81072,%'
WHERE (',' + RTRIM(lstclasses) + ',') LIKE '%,' + '8200' + ',%'
-- where (',' + RTRIM(lstclasses) + ',') LIKE '%,' + #arguments.cid# + ',%'
  AND isvoid = 0
```

Table rows:

```
ID      Name        lstclasses                       isVoid 
------------------------------------------------------------
1       Test1       8100,8200,8300,7600                0    
2       Test2       7520,8888,8754,8569                1
3       test3       8545,8566,7854,8569                1
4       Test4       8756,9874,8796,8547                1
5       Test5       1235,5423,5241,5632                1
```

above query will run and i want to do a search within the lstclasses column, i have a classid say in my parameter as `8200`, so `8200` will be the `search` and the **column to search** will be `lstclasses`

hope this helps what i am trying

Comment: Are you getting an error? What results are you getting, and what is the expected output? And what's the structure of response_students and response?

Comment: WHERE lstclasses LIKE '%8200%'

Comment: It would help if you actually posted the schema of your tables, your desired output (an example), and what you were getting instead.

Comment: the table has one row like, i am gonna edit my question

Comment: So what is your actual problem/error?

Comment: i am getting zero results even the value exists

Comment: check my edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @var VARCHAR(1000) = '8200'

SELECT *
FROM response_students
INNER JOIN response ON response_students.responseID = reponseID
WHERE lstclasses LIKE '%' + @var + '%'
AND isvoid = 0
```

Comment: no, it is giving me empty results adn i am not sure it is the correct way, because my column has multiple values as comma separated

Comment: My answer works on 2008 r2. Can you post the full schemas for response and response_students? Using LIKE as I have in my answer will still give you matches, regardless of delimiters.